# Segmentation fault when calling crypt function in C

Tags: c

I pass the argument Arturo $1$salt$ and I get a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error.

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if ( argc != 3) {
        printf ("Usage: ./crypt key salt\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("%s\n", crypt (argv[1], argv[2]));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You know there is now `string` type in `C`? Also what should `cs50.h`  library be?

Comment: Even if this were C++, you can't use a `string` for `main`'s arguments, it has to be `(int, char*[])`.  However, on second look, is `string` a typedef for `char*`?

Comment: Whatever `string` is can't you just do `crypt (argv[1], argv[2])`?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, I'm pretty sure it's just crypt(3) from libc

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin / RobLatham  Oh I see.

Comment: The string is just the same as char* but I'll change it

Comment: @Rizier123 There is no string type in C.  In C "A _string_ is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character." C11 7.1.1 Definitions of terms

Comment: @chux That is what i wrote! (Only that i now see i made a little type `now` -> `no`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer turned out to be simple - bash variable expansion. the `$` character is reserved in the shell, to mark the beginning of a variable

so when you run

```
./program Arturo $1$salt$
```

the `argv[2]` after variable expansion will be

```
"$"
```

which is not a valid salt after the glibc specification (which expects `$id$salt$`). The call to `crypt` with that seed will return `NULL` and set `errno` to `EINVAL`, because the seed is invalid, and the call to `printf` chokes on the `NULL` and segfaults, which is the behaviour you are seeing.

if you were to execute your program as follows, disabling variable expansion in the shell:

```
./program Arturo '$1$salt$'
```

the output would be

```
$1$salt$y5SOwLketmwNfSvW0yAoz/
```

as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

```
typedef char *string;
```

From `crypt` POSIX [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/crypt.html):

> The salt argument shall be a string of at least two bytes in length not including the null character chosen from the set:
>
> a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
>   A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
>   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 . /

but you pass `$1$salt$`.

So you have to check the return value of `crypt` and print only if is `! = NULL`.

Now, if you want to use `crypt` function from glibc, you have to include `crypt.h` header in your program. See example in glibc [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/crypt.html).

Comment: The format of `salt` is quite specific. http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/crypt.html

Comment: I'm using ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.19-10ubuntu2.1) 2.19

Comment: @Arturo please include `crypt.h` in that case

Comment: `crypt.h` only applies to the `crypt_r` function. (again, see the manpage)

Comment: I'm including it. It runs without problems if I pass arturo 01 as argument. But I can't run it with a salt beginning with $1$.

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin from http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/crypt.html  `crypt.h` is included when `crypt` is called in the example.

Comment: I don't think the example is a better reference than the actual manual.

Comment: @Arturo did you remove the `unistd.h` inclusion and the macro definition?